# Why can't programming language turn off select "features"

Tags: exception, dynamic, garbage-collection, runtime, programming-languages

As programming evolved over the years *(from assembler to high level languages)*, more and more features *(garbage collection, exceptions, dynamic typing)* have been added as standard to some languages. Is it possible to create a high level language that starts of with all features on by default, and once a program runs as well, then to be able to selectively **turn features of in code**, or have sections of code which a quarantined off so that they do not use these features. Perhaps modifying branches in the Abstract Syntax Tree to be statically typed, instead of dynamic; compiled, instead of interpreted.

Is there any programming language which can be used as dynamic and static, and also selectively turn of garbage collection, by releasing used objects, even up to disabling exception handling, all the way to the point where the run-time consist of only c like constructs, or any the above mentioned?

Comment: A language is just a language. Its *implementation* dictates how it behaves or doesn't behave. The same language can be interpreted *or* compiled, as the cited Python demonstrates very well. Python also happens to support arbitrary annotations, which can be used for static type checking, and in essence static typing.

Comment: For me a language consists of many things, such as the syntax, the implementation (the features), the community (how much shared resources and code is out there). The compiler for me is part of the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a language to do what you're asking, it would have to be built to support *both* alternatives: garbage collection and manual memory management or static and dynamic typing and make the two worlds interoperate.

In other words, what you're saying to be just "turn off A", is actually "design A, design B, design transitioning between A and B". So, doing this would be a significant amount of additional design and implementation work, it would make the language more complicated and the language might end up as "worst of both worlds".

Now, languages that support both combinations of the features you mentioned do exist, in a limited form:

- C# is normally a statically typed language, but it also has the `dynamic` keyword, which allows you to switch to dynamic typing for certain variables. This was primarily meant for interoperation with dynamic languages, and is not used much in practice.
- C++/CLI is a language that supports both manually managed memory, (`*` pointers, `new` to allocate and `delete` to deallocate) and garbage collected memory (`^` pointers, `gcnew` to allocate). It is primarily meant for interoperation between C++ code and .Net code and is not widely used in practice.

You might have noticed a theme here: in both cases, the feature/language were created to bridge the two worlds, but didn't gain much traction.